# How can I determine the original message of a reply?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph, how can I determine which message an outgoing message is a reply to?

The internetMessageHeaders property is not available for items in the Sent Items folder of mailboxes (using the Graph API, at least -- they are available using EWS or IMAP). If it were, I'd look for the in-reply-to header. In the absence of this, is there something in the standard Graph message properties that will tell me this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the "Subject" or "bodyPreview" to check if the content contains "RE:", if the answer is yes, the message is reply to.
2. You can group the message by conversationId and then order by lastModifiedDateTime. This way can check if the message is the original one, if it is not ,it will be reply-to/follow-up one.
3. Get the message list first(/me/messages or /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages and so on), and then foreach the message id to call reply api(/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/reply and so on). The result in the reply is a reply to.

To Test this, you can use the Graph Explorer first and then paste the JSON to a JSON viewer tool. For further use, you need to use net/java and so on to handle.

API reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_reply

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a method of reliably identifying the exact message that was replied to, just as the In-Reply-To header provides.